# Connection refused connecting to any port other than 1234

Tags: c, linux, sockets, port, host

I'm working on a chat bot that connects to a host and port. Although, any time I connect to any port other than "1234", I get a `connect: Connection refused` error. This seems to be caused by the socket, any ideas on why it only connects to the single port?

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include "parse.h"
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int choice(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds,
       struct timeval *timeout) {
    int n = select(nfds, readfds, writefds, exceptfds, timeout);
    if (n < 0) {
        perror("select");
        exit(1);
    }
    return(n);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s hostname [port number] ...\n", argv[0]);
        return(1);
    }

    int sockfd;
    char buf[500];
    struct hostent *hp;
    struct sockaddr_in peer;
    fd_set master;
    peer.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if (argc == 2) {
        peer.sin_port = htons(1234);
    } else {
        peer.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
    }


    //HOST
    if ((hp = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: no such host\n", argv[1]);
        return(1);
    }

    if (hp->h_addr_list[0] == NULL || hp->h_addrtype != AF_INET) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: not an internet protocol host name\n", argv[1]);
        return(1);
    }

    //SOCKET
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&peer, sizeof(peer)) == -1) {
        perror("connect");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(1);
    }

    FD_ZERO(&master);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &master);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &master);
    fd_set fds = master;

    //LOOP
    while(1) {
        choice(sockfd+1, &fds ,NULL,NULL,NULL);
        if(FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds)) {
            fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
            if (strlen(buf) > 0) { 
                printf("success");
                /*
                struct expr *e = parse(buf);
                if (e) {
                    printf("Hey XXX, %d\n", evalexpr(e));
                    freeexpr(e);
                } else {
                    printf("Hey XXX, I don't like that.\n[%s]\n", errorstatus);
                } */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I commented out a section of the code which requires extra code in order to keep the code minimal and replicable(?). I should be able to connect to ports such as 1235, 20000, 25000, etc.

Comment: You should be able to connect to any port that's in LISTEN state. Not just any old port.

Comment: `select()` modifies the `fd_set` variables that are passed to it, so you need to reset the `fds` variable on every loop iteration. On Linux, `select()` also modifies the `timeval` variable if one is passed in, so you would have to reset that as well (if you were using one).

Comment: I don't like this question because it uses a function that every decent piece of documentation clearly states is **deprecated**, in favour of an alternative that makes protocol-independent communication (e.g. works on IPV4 and IPV6 without modification) but more importantly is **cleaner and easier to use** and would have likely made the error stick out like a sore thumb.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I believe I am resetting it here: 
`while(1) {

 choice(sockfd+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if(FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds)) {`

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh: That is not resetting the `fds` variable.  It is calling `select()` and then checking whether `STDIN_FILENO` is contained in `fds` after `select()` has modified it. To actually reset `fds`, you need to move the `fd_set fds = master;` assignment **inside** the loop before calling `select()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for that, from your other comment though: I can't use `getaddrinfo()` as I'm supposed to use `gethostname()` per assignment restrictions. The below answer `peer.sin_addr = *((in_addr*)(hp->h_addr_list[0]));` gives me an `in_addr undeclared` error. Is this caused by the use of `gethostname()`?

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh try using `(struct in_addr*)` instead of `(in_addr*)`. I'm so used to programming in C++ that I forget C requires the `struct` prefix on structure type names. C++ does not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the follow up, but I still get the original `connect: Connection refused` error

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh that error means you are trying to connect to an IP/port that is not actually listening for connections. You cannot just connect to any arbitrary ip/port you want, it has to be in an open and listening state on the remote side. Also, `gethostbyname()` can return a list of IPs (just like `getaddrinfo()` can). Try looping through all of the returned IPs. Maybe your client PC does not have a network route to reach the first IP, but might be able to reach another IP, if multiple IPs are reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking up the hostname, but you are never transferring the resulting IP address into `peer`, so you are not actually connecting to the host.  You need to add this:

```
peer.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr*)(hp->h_addr_list[0]));
```

Comment: While technically correct, do note that `gethostbyname()` is deprecated, you should be using `getaddrinfo()` instead. It returns a linked list of `sockaddr_in` and/or `sockaddr_in6` objects (depending on what you ask for) which can be passed as-is to `connect()`.  Loop through the list until one of the addresses succeeds or the list is exhausted.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the edit. I didn't write anything about `gethostname()`. Presumably your comment is addressed to the OP?